Counterexample for a proof

Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers and
$$T = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{N}^3 \mid 1 \leq x,y,z \leq n \}$$
be a lattice cube of length $n$.
Suppose that $3n^2 - 3n + 1 + k$ points of $T$ are colored red so that if $P$ and $Q$ are red points and $PQ$ is parallel to one of the coordinate axes, then the whole line segment $PQ$ consists of only red points.
Prove that there exists at least $k$ unit cubes of length $1$, all vertices of which are colored red.
(Source: China Mathematical Olympiad 2018 Q2).

I came up with a proof, but a friend told me that a certain claim used in the proof was once disproved by someone else, yet he could not pinpoint the flaws in the claim. Could someone give me a counterexample?
Sketch of my proof:
First, if $k = (n - 1)^3$, then all the points are red, and there are $(n - 1)^3$ cubes of length $1$.
Next, use induction to prove that for any other $k$, there are $k$ unit cubes. Assume that it is true for $k = m$, consider $k = m - 1$.
I claim that one more point can be colored red so that the new configuration still satisfies the condition. By the induction hypothesis, there are $m$ unit cubes. And then we move this point out, it's obvious that at most a unit cube is no longer all red. Induction done.
They said my claim is wrong, because there are situations that we can't color just a single point.

To use the inductive hypothesis, the new point must be such that the "whole line segment" condition is still satisfied. How do you know that you can pick such a point?

That's the problem. At first I thought it's obvious. However, I failed to give a specific method. I still thought it was right until my friend said there is counterexample. So I want to know what's the example.

I think there will always exist some point which can be added which will still satisfy the "whole line segment" condition, but that's what you have to prove. It will likely require careful (possibly nontrivial) geometric/combinatorial reasoning.

I think it's right, but someone told me a teacher gave a counterexampe few years ago.

Not all values of $k$ have valid configurations, so it cannot be proved using induction like that. In particular, if $k=(n-1)^3-1$ then only one point in the lattice is uncoloured. Then any axis-parallel line through that uncoloured point has $n-1$ red points, so (assuming $n>2$) violates the condition. Secondly, a lattice point can belong to up to 8 unit cubes, so how can it be obvious that making it not red only removes one red unit cube?

For the first question, to meet the condition, only one of the eight points on the corner can be uncolored. For the latter, because of the condition, this point (we add) must be the end point. So the 8 unit cubes contain at most one red. BTW, I've got the counterexample, but I don't know how to put it on.

In order to reply to someone's comment, you need to use the @ to notify them: "@JaapScherphuis". You get notified of all comments on your post. But others are only notified when the @ is used. Your reply does not address Jaap's issues. When $n > 2$, removing any single point from having all $n^3$ points red does not give a valid coloration, even when it is one of the eight corners. Because the vertical line through the non-red point has at least two other points on it, which are both red, the line condition requires the non-red point to be red as well, so it cannot be removed.

@PaulSinclair Thanks for advice. But I still don't think the problem lies in what you said. A point must be red if it's between two red points(it's segment$PQ$, not a line). I think you're using a stronger condition. Since the eight corners cannot be in the middle of other two, so that uncolor it is possible. But there are other times we cannot color only one point.

You are right - I was interpreting it as "line segment through $P$ and $Q$", i.e., the intersection of the line with the cube. But re-reading it, I see that is not what you wrote. My apologies.

Here's the example.
Let all the points colored red except one layer (the upper layer). And if this layer looks like this, we'll be unable to only color a point.




r









r


r







r




